# How can I rotate picture dynamically?

Tags: image, rotation, c++builder, angle

I have a resource in my prog (*.bmp image). When I start a timer, my image should rotate until I click "pause". I need a sample which explain me how I could to do this.

Currently I use this code:

```
void rotatewaiticon()
{
Graphics::TBitmap *bmpOriginal = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    //bmpOriginal->LoadFromResourceName(0,"bmpcrug");
    bmpOriginal->LoadFromFile("degrees.bmp");
    FormMain->Image65->Picture->Assign(bmpOriginal);
Graphics::TBitmap *bmpCopy = new Graphics::TBitmap();

    bmpCopy->Width  = bmpOriginal->Height;
    bmpCopy->Height = bmpOriginal->Width;

    int wOr = bmpOriginal->Width, hOr = bmpOriginal->Height;
    for(int x = 0; x < wOr; x++)
    {
      for(int y = 0; y < hOr; y++)
      {
            bmpCopy->Canvas->Pixels[hOr - y][x] = bmpOriginal->Canvas->Pixels[x][y];
      }
    }
/**/FormMain->Image65->Picture->Assign(bmpCopy);
    bmpCopy->SaveToFile("degrees.bmp");

    delete bmpOriginal, bmpCopy;
}
```

But I don't see a way to work with this file without saving it on a disk.

Comment: See this article: [How to rotate a bitmap](http://www.leunen.com/cbuilder/rotbmp.html)